# how to change the inner element tuple into list?

Tags: python

```
>>> x=[[(1,2,3),(10,9,8)]]
>>> x
[[(1, 2, 3), (10, 9, 8)]]
>>>
```

I want to change the inner tuple element in x into list ,that is to say ,change x into

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [10, 9, 8]]]
```

how can i do that ?
how can i get it with for loop not list comprehension?

```
for unit in x:
    for cell in unit:
        cell=list(cell)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use List comprehension, like this

```
x = [[(1, 2, 3), (10, 9, 8)]]
print [[list(item) for item in items] for items in x]
# [[[1, 2, 3], [10, 9, 8]]]
```

This is similar to

```
result = []
for items in x:
    temp = []
    for item in items:
        temp.append(list(item))
    result.append(temp)
print result
# [[[1, 2, 3], [10, 9, 8]]]
```

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Assigning a new object to `cell` in the loop will not change the actual object `cell` refers to.